# XSLT Transformation of date format [2100-10-10T23:59:59.000Z]; adding GMT timezone

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am very new to XSLT transform, facing an issue with XSLT transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
<headers>
    <status>Success</status>
    <requestTime>2017-10-10T23:59:59.000Z</requestTime>
    <Date>2500-10-10T23:59:59.000Z</Date>
</headers>
<results>
    <partyId></partyId>
    <contId></contId>
    <identifier>
        <number>987651435</number>
        <type>SSN</type>
        <status>PRIMARY</status>
        <expiryDate>2100-10-10T23:59:59.000Z</expiryDate>
    </identifier>
    <identifier>
        <number>123456789</number>
        <type>CL</type>
        <status>SECONDARY</status>
        <expiryDate>2100-10-10T10:00:59.000Z</expiryDate>
    </identifier>
    <address>
        <street>Anantha Nagar Phase 2</street>
        <city>Bangalore</city>
        <country>
            <code>IN</code>
        </country>
        <state>
            <code>KA</code>
        </state>
    </address>
    <officerNo>7654345</officerNo>
    <entityCode>005</entityCode>
    <birthDate>1991-12-13T01:01:00.000Z</birthDate>
</results>
```

I would want to transform all tags with value that matches the regex pattern of the date provided and add timezone i.e +00:00 at the end instead of Z.

Could you please provide any inputs on the above.

Comment: There is no regex in XSLT 1.0. You can make a template matching the date elements by their names. Then extract the first 23 characters (or the substring before "Z") and add the timezone string.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  You will have to figure out what time zone value you want concatenated to the date as it is not specified in your XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <!-- To match the date pattern, key off of some of the constants in the date string. 
       (The below match uses only some of the constants.)
  -->
  <xsl:template match="*[substring(.,5,1)='-' and substring(.,8,1)='-'  and substring(.,14,1)=':']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Do transform here. Below is an example. -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(.,'Z'), '+00:00')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity template. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```